# Compare two rows (HTML Table) data i.e..row[i] with row[i+1] and highlight changes using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

Compare two rows data i.e.. `row[i]` with `row[i+1]` and highlight changes using `Jquery/Javascript`. It is for showing history of a artifact. Went through a lot of answers and  drew a blank. Any help with a `jsfiddle` example will be appreciated.

Want something transpose of exactly what this fiddle does.. http://jsfiddle.net/hA5G8/18/ .Its comparing columns within same row. Just have to compare columns between rows.

Comment: Would be a good idea if you would post some code, and point out with what you are having trouble with. Makes it easier for other to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lbuxpmyq/1/

Thanks!!

HTML

```
                <table id="coa_history_data">
                <tr class="data-in-table">
                    <th>old Name</th>
                    <th>New Name</th>
                    <th>Old Phone</th>
                    <th>New Phone</th>
                    <th>Old Age</th>
                    <th>New Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-in-table">
                        <td>Alphy</td>
                        <td>Alphy</td>
                        <td>015</td>//should be highlited
                        <td>016</td>//should be highlited
                        <td>23</td>//should be highlited
                        <td>24</td>//should be highlited</tr>
                    <tr class="data-in-table">
                        <td>Tom</td>
                        <td>Tom</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>65</td>//should be highlited
                        <td>30</td>//should be highlited</tr>
                    <tr class="data-in-table">
                        <td>will</td>
                        <td>will</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JQuery

```
$("#coa_history_data tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function () {
            var i=0;
                $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    var currentCell = $(this);
                    var nextCell = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(i).length > 0 ? $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(i) : null;
                    if ( currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                        currentCell.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
                    }
                    i=i+1;
                });
            });
```